# Odoo 16V, how to clear cache?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

How to clear cache or maybe some other problem?

1. Installed my module
2. Goes to product grid
3. On product grid displayed 'date_planned' from 'purchase.order' model
4. After manualy changed value for  '**date_planned**' and goes back to Product grid
5. Still seen the old value from '**date_planned**'

```
   def _compute_expected_delivery(self):
        
       for product in self:
           # get all name from purchase.order
           if product.default_code != False:
               full_product_name = product.default_code + " " + product.name
           else:
               full_product_name = product.name

           # get only name field
           all_name_field = http.env['purchase.order'].search([])

           for name in all_name_field:
               # get all product_id from purchase.order

               for order_line in name.order_line:
                   product2 = order_line.product_id
                   product_name = product2.name
                   product_reference = product2.default_code
                   if product_reference != False:
                       if full_product_name == product_reference + " " + product_name:
                           
                           product.expected_delivery = name.date_planned
                           # Clear cache for the updated product
                           product.invalidate_cache()
                           self.env['product.template'].invalidate_cache()
                           break
```

Maybe some problem with cache? How to load new 'date_planned' data every time when I go to product grid?

Comment: Your question it's not clear to me, could you be more specific?

Comment: When I go to Purchase. Create Purchase order and install  Expect Delivery Data.  After want display Expected Delivery Time on my product grid. When I go to Products and all work good, data displayed on product grid, but if I back to Purchase and change Delivery Data, and back to Products, then date still old